# Calculating accuracy, error, full scale error, relative error and more in a specific case

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, atmospheric-science, error-analysis, si-units

I recently bought a O2(oxygen) sensor and I am trying to figure out the error in the percentage O2 (O2pct, unitless but in %) output value that it gives out.  This error is not stated in its data sheet unfortunately.

To understand my problem you need the following information.
The sensor internally contains an oxygen partial pressure sensor (ppO2) and a barometric pressure sensor (bP). These 2 provide independent values in `mbar` units. Then calculating the O2% is simply

```
O2pct(%) = ppO2(mbar)/bP(mbar) * 100    (1)   (the units are in parenthesis)
```

The data sheet provides the following accuracy specification for the 2 sensors:

```
bP sensor: accuracy = +/-5(mbar) , range = 500-1200(mbar)
ppO2 sensor: accuracy = <2%FS , range = 0-300(mbar)
```

It is certainly weird that one sensor error is provided in FS and the other in absolute value, but oh well.

Now comes the 1st tricky part which puzzles me. This ppO2=2%**FS** is the **full scale** error. For a definition see [here (chapter 2.3)](http://www.ginstruments.com/appnotes/AN103.pdf) but basically

```
FSerror(%) = ABSerror / S.R * 100    (2)
```

where `ABSerror=absolute error(mbar)` , and `S.R.=sensor range(mbar)`.

Also, as I will need to divide the 2 soon, lets bring them under the same units:

```
Error ppO2(mbar) = +/-6(mbar)
Error bP(%FS) = 5(mbar) / (1200-500)(mbar) = 0.71%FS
```

so how we can do all the combinations (either both errors in mbar or in %FS) that may arise.

in order to do the division of (1) , I need to "add the 2 relative uncertainties" (which I had to refresh in my memory , from [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Uncertainty) - scroll to method 3of3 , part 4 = dividing uncertainties)

so ideally I would find the relative errors.

```
RELerr(%) = ABSerr(mbar) / real value(mbar).     (3)
```

add them, and in the end multiply the sum of the uncertainties , with the O2pct(%) value from the division, in order to find ABSerr for O2pct (see (5) below). So

```
RELerr(O2pct in %) = RELerr(ppO2 in %) + RELerr(bP in %)                  (4) 

ABSerr(O2pct in %) = O2pct(%) * RELerr(O2pct in %)                        (5)
ABSerr(O2pct in %) = O2pct(%) * [ RELerr(ppO2 in %) + RELerr(bP in %) ]   (6)
```

right?

I have absolute errors for both quantities, but I don't have a real value for either. I could use the maximum of the ppO2 sensor (300mbar), but that would give me exactly the FSerror (`FSerr(ppO2) = RELerr(ppO2) = 2%`). And for bP, taking the minimum in the range (500) would maximise the error to `RELerr(bP)=1%`, but why should I not use the other end of the range (1200mbar) which would give `RELerr(bP)=0.42%`?

This led to confusion and I decided to use the FSerr values that I had acquired, which are also constant across all acquired values , so (4) would become:

```
FSerr(O2pct in %) = FSerr(ppO2 in %) + FSerr(bP in %)
```

What is more , since this is the *full scale* aggregate error, it should not need to be rectified to get an absolute value as we need to do in (6). Is this preposition even correct?).

Finally,

```
FSerr = 2% + 0.71% = 2.71%
```

So lets think of an example. On sea level, bP=1013.25(mbar)+/-5(mbar) and ppO2=211.72(mbar)+/-6(mbar). Then

```
O2pct = 20.90% +/- 2.71%(fs)      (7)
```

so value 23.61% is just within the acceptable range. BUT, if I try to find the using absolute->relative->absolute transition for the errors, the analysis becomes:

RELerr(ppO2) = 6(mbar)/211.72(mbar) = 2.8%
RELerr(bP) = 5(mbar)/1013.25(mbar) = 0.49%

then

```
RELerr(O2pct) = 3.29%
ABSerr(O2pc) = 3.29% * 20.90% = 0.69%
```

so the result from (7), then becomes

```
O2pct = 20.90% +/- 0.69%(abs)       (8)
```

And the final (and main) question is:

```
is (7) or (8) correct?
```

I mean the absolute error and the full scale are not supposed to be the same thing, for non % quantities ABSerr wouldn't have % as units anyway, but which one should I use?

thank you and forgive me for the long question

================================

### EDIT:

following the commentator, I used a different approach to calculate the propagated uncertainty of the O2pct variable. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example_formulas) I used the st.dev. for 
$$
f= \frac{A}{B} $$ and $$\sigma _{f}=\left | f \right | \sqrt{ \left (\frac{\sigma _{A}}{A} \right )^{2}+ \left ( \frac{\sigma _{B}}{B}  \right )^{2}- 2 \frac{\sigma _{AB}}{AB}}
$$

So from the inputs I have explained above I have :

σA = 6mbar

σB = 5mbar

also the covariance of the 2 variables is assumed to be 0. It is not specified in the datasheet and I will not generate sample data at this time to calculate it. Either way, this is a safe assumption as it maximises `σf`.

So using an example case

```
A = ppO2 = 101.33 mbar                   (9)
B = bP   = 500.00 mbar
```

then

```
f = A/B = O2pct = 20.27 %                        (10)
σf = 1.22 %
```

This is fine and it means that for a real value of O2pct = 20.27%, I may read anything in the range = `19.05% - 21.49%` on my instrument. Right?

So far so good, but once again I would like to try and calculate `f` by taking extreme case of the inputs A and B. I assume I can do that (if not, why not?). If the values are not related, then I can assume that

```
A = ppO2 = 101.33 +/-6 mbar               (11)
B = bP = 500 +/- 5 mbar
```

worst case (maximising deviation form real value)

```
A = 107.33 mbar                           (12)
B = 495 mbar
```

Say the real A & B are just as they were in (9). But on my instrument I due to errors I read the values of (12).

In this case,

```
f = 21.68 %                               (13)
```

So my question is (13) is outside of the range of (10). Why?

Comment: You lost me near the end, but that wiki site is incorrect in how it finds the error on two measured values. The error on something like $A/B$ is $\sqrt{(\sigma_A/B)^2+(A\sigma_B/B^2)^2}$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty. The formula you have is the linearized version.

Comment: and I lost you with the A/B  function. how did you derive it? in the link you provided, I see a different definition that involves co-variance calculation (but it don't have random variable here, only 2 values (A,B) and 2 uncertainties(σΑ , σΒ)

Comment: @levitopher hi there. please check the updated question. I have edited to include the propagation of uncertainty from wikipedia. Also please see my previous comment.

Comment: The definition of propagation of error for a function $f(x,y)$ is $\sqrt{(\partial f/\partial x)^2\sigma_x^2+(\partial f/\partial y)^2\sigma_y^2}$. See the section "Non-linear Combinations" on that wikipedia page. It's just a bit different from what you're not using because it assumes the errors are small. I think either would be fine for this application.